# UITableView NSFetchedResultsController philosophy

Tags: uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uianimation

I am displaying data from `CoreData` in a `UITableView` using `NSFetchedResultsController` as the container for the `NSManagedObjects`.  The code for deleting a row works well, but my implementation strikes me as less than elegant.  Is there a better way?

The code below illustrates the deletion event:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        // Delete the row from the data source 
       [myContext deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        if (![myContext save:&error]) { 
            // Error handling
        }  

        fetchedResultsController = nil;

        if (![[self getFetchedResultController] performFetch:&error]) {
             // Error handling
        }
        [tableView reloadData];        
    }   
}
```

I set the `fetchedResultsController` to `nil` and perform another fetch to update the new contents.

What concerns me is that I have seen references on various forums hinting that a change in the context should automatically engender changes in the fetchedResultsController and perhaps this second fetch is unnecessary. I have not implemented sections at this point.

Another concern is that the code simply makes the row disappear without any animation.

Could some slick animation be introduced?

Comment: Also - is there anyway to get email notification of a response on this forum?

Answer (score 2):

Look into using the [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate Protocol methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to manage changes to the table and the database. This way, whenever you do a save within the NSManagedObjectContext of the NSFetchedResultsController, that fetchedResultsController will be notified by the managed ojbect context. Then the fetchedResultsCotnroller will call its delegate methods.

You want to implement controllerWillChangeContent: and controllerDidChangeContent: so you can bracket the calls of the other delegate methods with calls to the beginUpdates and endUpdates methods for the table view. (See the example in the reference.) **This keeps the table view from getting out of synchronization with the fetchedResultsController.**

Then delete these line:

```
 fetchedResultsController = nil;

        if (![[self getFetchedResultController] performFetch:&error]) {
             // Error handling
        }
        [tableView reloadData];
```

Once you have done this, you can introduce animations in the insertion and deletion of cells.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I definitely need to do some more homework on this issue -  I'll start with your reference.  The delegate methods you list are in my program but are not currently being called, so I felt there must be something amiss.  I thought I had implemented the protocol but something is off.  I'll give it some more thought and research.

Comment: There's actually a good example in the Apple projects - CoreData Books - It does pretty much what I want - BUT it doesn't use a storyboard.  So I'm trying to do the translation to the new environment.

Comment: Make sure you set the fetchedResultsController's delegate to the controller that has the delegate methods in it.

Comment: Jim - you nailed it - thanks!  I did declare the delegate - but before I actually allocated the fetchedResultsController.  DOH!  But your hint showed me my stupid mistake.  I'll buy ya a drink someday.